# Accessing Virtual Machine From A VPN Client (Cisco AnyConnect)

Tags: centos, centos7, virtualbox, cisco-vpn, anyconnect

I have a CentOS 7 server running on a virtualbox that we use for hosting an in-house local website.

The network settings of the VM are configured with:

- Bridged as adapter 1
- NAT as adapter 2

The server is configured in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 with:

- BOOTPROTO=static
- IPADDR=192.168.0.240
- NETMASK=255.255.255.0
- GATEWAY=192.168.0.141 (host computer ip)

Our DHCP server reserves a static IP based on the VM's mac address.

**This configuration works great when browsing while connected to the same network.** We can browse and use the internal website from any machine connected to our network.

My only problem is that when we try to connect using a VPN (Cisco AnyConnect) from an offsite location, we cannot reach the above address of the server. We can reach any other IP addresses on our system from the VPN, but not the VM's. Pinging the VM from the client running the VPN times out every time, but if we ping the host machine of the VM from the client we can get a response.

Cisco AnyConnect is using Split Include as it's IPV4 Tunnel Mode and is set to allow local (LAN) access when using VPN.

This all started when we did a reset of our DHCP server and the VM, which the system was functioning correctly before. Is something configured incorrectly or did a setting in VirtualBox get reset?